# ASUS M5A78L-M LX3 network drivers - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, hardware, motherboard

I"ve recently changed my motherboard to **ASUS M5A78L-M LX3**. After that internet on my **Ubuntu 12.04** stopped working. I've tried to install drivers included on a DVD by Asus, but it says "you need kernel 2.6 or older". Keep in mind that Ubuntu 12.04 is built on 3.2.

Is there something I can do without reinstalling whole OS?

Thanks in andvance.

P.S. I have Windows on same PC and it works fine so I can download anything. Thought I don't want to use Git in this situation if possible.

EDIT1: Controller Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your device (I assume ethernet) from the terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0200` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution myself.

1. [Download this](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/)
2. Install alx driver with:

   ```
   make defconfig-alx
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: You will need to re-install it after each kernel upgrade. I suggest upgrading distro to 14.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, you're right. Thanks. Yet I needed connection to do this.

Comment: As @Pilot6 implies, the driver `alx` is included in 14.04 LTS by default.